# hidden array returns OK but text array is empty html to PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays

Form:

```
<form method="POST" action="edit_work.php">

<input type="hidden" name="wid[]"  size="1" value="<?php echo "$wid1" ?>" >
<input type="text" name="course[]"  size="15" value="<?php echo "$course1" ?>" >
```

PHP:

```
extract($_POST);  
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)  { 
    echo $wid[$i];   
    echo $course[$i]; 
}
```

gives the wid values OK but not the text entered for the course names.

I have been through all forums for 2 days now. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Show what your POST contains.

Comment: you are iterating using `$count` variable. Where is this set?

Comment: echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST) ;  echo "</pre>";
gives
Array
(
    [wid] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14
            [1] => 15
            [2] => 16
            [3] => 18
            [4] => 19
        )

    [course] => 
    [work] => 
    [what] => 
    [wdate] => 
    [nstu] => 
    [nques] => 
    [nhrs] => 
    [nmin] => 
    [person_res] => 
    [update] => Update Above
)
as you can see only the hidden array is full, all others which are text are empty.

$count is set just before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your PHP to retrieve your data from the form, can't you name your text input "course", then get it inside your PHP with `$_POST['course']` ?

What is your `$count` ?

Using brackets with your `name` attribute inside your `input` tag may be dangerous.
If you're using a list of inputs maybe you can define a text format like `name="course#"` where # is your index and then access it form your `$_POST` variable using `$_POST['course'.$index]`

You don't need to `extract($_POST)` in that case.

Comment: $count assumes a value above (as a result of the row count from a query)

Comment: * $count assumes a value above (as a result of the row count from a query)
* I am allowing the user to edit multiple lines on the form. The form lists all the courses he entered previously. He may edit the ones he wishes, all, one, none. Then he submits the form. The data is then extracted and the table will be updated with the courses,
SETting course=$_POST['course'][$i] where wid=$_POST["wid"] thanks..

Comment: Updated possible answer